# android phone not connecting to the internet

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

My phone does not connecting to the Internet – it's saying "connected,no internet":

[image: screenshot]

When I open a web browser, all I get is the same message ("no connection").

Can some one help me please I am begging. I have tried so many things and nothing work.

Comment: Have you tried another Wi-Fi network? Usually this indicates a problem with this particular network.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see The SSID of available network's. When you click on the SSID does it say connect but no internet? Press and hold the SSID and select forget this will disconnect then reconnect make sure the password is correct if no password the you may need to agree to the terms

Comment: yes i did that every day still no improvement

Answer (score 0):

The message "connected, no internet" usually indicates a [captive portal](/tags/captive-portal/info). In short that means you are connected to the router, but without your first "identifying" to it it won't "let you out" but rather "holds you captive".

In modern Android versions (Android 6 and up at least), Android detects this situation by itself (hence the message) and offers you to "identify" to the portal (it shows you a notification to tap on):

[image: connected, no internet] [image: catpive portal]
<sup>"No Internet" / Captive Portal (source: [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Starbucks_Captive_Portal.png), click to enlarge)</sup>

If that does not happen, simply open your web browser and try to open a page, e.g. `www.google.com`. Your browser then should automatically take you to the login-page of the portal first.

Comment: am using a modem

Comment: And what did the browser itself show: "no connection", or cannot find/access the site, or just displaying some other page?

Comment: no connection  that's all

Comment: OK, that makes a captive portal unlikely. Could you please edit your question and add those details (best with a screenshot)? Also still unanswered: What do you mean by "using a modem"?

Comment: router - modem that's what we call it

Comment: Ah, so the usual stuff. Well, yes, for WiFi one uses a router of course :) So does that happen with every WiFi router you connect to, or just with this specific one?